# Unknown Alien Robot Set

Tags: set-identification

My grandsons are intrigued by the LEGO robot that is partially assembled. However we cannot locate the instructions to complete the assembly. Does anyone recognize and know what LEGO set this is?

[image: this robot]

Answer (score 11):

That looks like a part of [Set 7313 - Red Planet Protector](https://brickset.com/sets/7313-1/Red-Planet-Protector) a set from 2001

Comment: It sure is - thanks a lot.  My 6 year old grandsons are finding my son's partial Lego projects and they are really getting into Legos.  We are trying to reassemble the disassembled sets from boxes and boxes of Lego pieces.  It looks like we have some searching to do on this one.  Great site - thanks again.

Comment: @LOS Welcome to Bricks! I'm glad we've been able to help you find the answer to your first question - if you're able to press the grey tick below the votes on Henrik's answer you'll both get some reputation, and we'll know that your question has been solved.